# How to navigate to new page using flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I want to click each navigation item and direct it to another activity.

I actually want to show the `list view` of 'now playing movie'.

When I click that drawer item, I have no idea how to display it, please help me

**My code**

**navigation_drawer.dart** looks like:

```
class NavigationDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.black,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24.0, 80, 24, 0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              DrawerItem(
                name: 'Now playing',
                icon: Icons.play_circle_outline,
                onPressed: ()=> onItemPressed(context, index: 0),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30,),
              DrawerItem(
                  name: 'Popular',
                  icon: Icons.analytics_outlined,
                  onPressed: ()=> onItemPressed(context, index: 1)
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30,),
              DrawerItem(
                  name: 'Top Rated',
                  icon: Icons.star_border,
                  onPressed: ()=> onItemPressed(context, index: 2)
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30,),
              DrawerItem(
                  name: 'Upcoming',
                  icon: Icons.ondemand_video,
                  onPressed: ()=> onItemPressed(context, index: 3)
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30,),
              const Divider(thickness: 1, height: 10, color: Colors.grey,),
              const SizedBox(height: 30,),
              DrawerItem(
                  name: 'About',
                  icon: Icons.settings,
                  onPressed: ()=> onItemPressed(context, index: 4)
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 30,),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onItemPressed(BuildContext context, {required int index}){
    Navigator.pop(context);

    switch(index){
      case 0:
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NowPlayingPages(nowplayingpages: ,)));
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

This keeps telling me that I need to put the arguments on it, but I didn't know what argument to use:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NowPlayingPages()));
```

**nowplaying_pages.dart:**

```
class NowPlayingPages extends StatelessWidget {
  final List nowplayingpages;

  const NowPlayingPages({Key? key, required this.nowplayingpages}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          modified_text(text:'Now Playing', size: 26,color: Colors.white,),
          SizedBox(height: 37,),
          Container(height: 297,
            child: ListView.builder(itemCount: nowplayingpages.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> Description(
                        name: nowplayingpages[index]['title'],
                        bannerurl:
                        'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' +
                            nowplayingpages[index]['backdrop_path'],
                        posterurl:
                        'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' +
                            nowplayingpages[index]['poster_path'],
                        description: nowplayingpages[index]['overview'],
                        vote: nowplayingpages[index]['vote_average']
                            .toString(),
                        launch_on: nowplayingpages[index]
                        ['release_date'],
                      )));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 167,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height:227,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(image :DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                    'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + nowplayingpages[index]['poster_path']
                                )
                            )),
                          ),
                          Container(child: modified_text(text:nowplayingpages[index]['title']!=null?
                          nowplayingpages[index]['title']:'Loading', size: 14, color: Colors.white,))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You created the `NowPlayingPages` class with a required parameter `nowplayingpages`. That's the parameter you need to provide.

Answer (score 0):

In your NowPlayingPages class you have a field

```
final List nowplayingpages;
```

that's why flutter asking for arguments.. otherwise you can remove above mentioned field and you have to fetch the data from NowPlayingPages class onload and send it to listview